# Can HTML Select Tag work with Hidden Text Input?

Tags: html

I am not sure if Select Tag can work with Hidden Text Input like this:

```
<SELECT NAME="Testing">  
  <OPTION VALUE="1"> One </option> 
  <input type="hidden" value="hello" name="Testing">
  <OPTION VALUE="2"> Two </option>
  <input type="hidden" value="world" name="Testing">   
</SELECT>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you need that's lacking in just reading the values of the `<option>` element that a user selects?

Comment: Why not use hidden variables directly after the opening <form> element. What are you trying to do here... are you looking for the selected attribute? http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected

Comment: why u want to use input tag with SELECT ? :-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work, but this will:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" value="hello" name="Testing">
<input type="hidden" value="world" name="Testing">   
<SELECT NAME="Testing">  
  <OPTION VALUE="1"> One </option> 
  <OPTION VALUE="2"> Two </option>
</SELECT>
</form>
```

Now judging from your code, it looks like you want Testing=hello if the first option is selected and Testing=world if the second option is selected.  In that case, do it like this:

```
<SELECT NAME="Testing">  
  <OPTION VALUE="hello"> One </option> 
  <OPTION VALUE="world"> Two </option>
</SELECT>
```