# HTML working with tags

Tags: html

Can I put `<input>` tag inside `<select>` tag?
For example:

```
<select name=""><option value="">Name1</option><input type="hidden" name=""/></select>
```

Comment: Your question is interesting and difficult at the same time approved if the answer were you? Send message

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

The short answer: Not really. Or more technically: yes, but it won't do anything different than if it was placed outside of the select element in the case of hidden input elements, or will either render unpredictably or not at all in the case of non-hidden input elements.

What are you trying to do?

Hidden input fields are provided to pass along info we can't get from the user via form controls. If you want one inside of a form control, that implies that you want some information from the user.

If you want to be able to have the user select an option that they then provide (ie, 'How did you hear about us? Web, print, _______') , the standard UI practice is to usually have them select an 'Other' option and then fill out a separate 'Other' text input. You can hide/swap these out with Javascript, but it's functionally still the same process.

Comment: This might also be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262679/can-html-select-tag-work-with-hidden-text-input?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

There is no optimal way to solve this problem is also complicated control is the easiest way below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnDropDownChange(dropDown) {
    var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("txtSelectedCity").value = selectedValue;
}
```

```
    <form action = "">
        <select name = "Cities" onChange="OnDropDownChange(this);">
          <option value="----">--Select--</option>
          <option value="B1">B1</option>
          <option value="B2">B2</option>
          <option value="B3">B3</option>

        </select>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Test">
        <input type="text" id="txtSelectedCity" name="SelectedCity" value="" />
    </form>
```